# Compact way to check if "dictionary item exists and is not blank" in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm parsing a 1970s-era text file (originally from the CDC 6600) which contains lines with variable numbers of parameters. Here are some samples...

```
GW 1 5 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000000 0.00000 1.0000 0.000 .00667
GE 1
FR 0 0 0 0 46.29 0.
```

I am using `split` (yay, finally fixed in Xcode 7!) to break this down into an array, and then insert non-zero values into a dictionary, like this...

```
let parts: [String] = original!.characters.split{ $0 == " " || $0 == "," }.map{ String($0).trim() }
if parts.count > 1 { data["I1"] = parts[1] }
if parts.count > 2 { data["I2"] = parts[2] }
if parts.count > 3 { data["F1"] = parts[3] }
```

Finally, I sanity check the inputs, because I've seen many examples of incorrect files. So I have a series of functions like this...

```
func checkGA() {
    if (data["I1"] == "" || data["I2"] == "" || data["F1"] == "" || data["F2"] == "" || data["F3"] == "" || data["F4"] == "") { problem = "Missing parameters." }
    if (data["F5"] != "" || data["F6"] != "" || data["F7"] != "") { problem = "Extra paramters after F4." }
}
```

I have a feeling there might be a less ugly way to check these inputs in Swift. I was thinking that perhaps I could use the range operator in a map or similar? Something along the lines of:

```
if (data["F2"..."F4"] != "") ...
```

But this sort of functional programming is very very new to me. Any gurus have a suggestion?

Comment: only thing I can think of is when setting your values, have a condition to not set the key if empty,  then all you need to do is check if the key exists or not.  `if (parts.count > 1 && parts[1] != "") { data["I1"] = parts[1] }`

Comment: Actually the key will not be set if empty, it's just one of those nice side effects of the split...trim which won't produce empty values. I've touched the Q to clarify a possibility

Comment: Don't know of any short hand that works like that,  since dictionary is an unordered list, the ... would have no meaning.  Also  if the split is not allowing the "",  Then whereever it is getting the empty string, do not allow it to be placed in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using error handling:

```
enum FieldError : ErrorType {
    case MissingField(String)
    case ExtraField(String,String)
}

do {
    // sample data
    let data = ["I1": "hello", "I2": "world", "F1":"Greetings" ]

    try ["I1", "I2", "F1"].forEach { key in
        guard let value = data[key] where value != "" else {
            throw FieldError.MissingField(key)
        }
    }

    try ["F5", "F6", "F7", "F8"].forEach { key in
        if let value = data[key] where value != "" {
            throw FieldError.ExtraField(key, value)
        }
    }

    print("All data tests passed")
}
catch FieldError.MissingField(let key) {
    print("Missing field for key: \(key)")
}
catch let FieldError.ExtraField(key, value) {
    print("Extra field with key: \(key), value: \(value)")
}
```

Comment: Wait, I think you nailed it there. The syntax I was looking for is in those try blocks - not so much the try itself, but the solution to making a list to iterate. That was almost exactly what I'm looking for, all I have to do is use the foreach on the min-array as you do. That's much clearer than all the || in my code.

Comment: Oh yes, this is precisely what I needed! I did `["I1", "I2"].forEach { k in let v = data[k]; if v == "" { problem = "Missing parameters." } }' That might not look any shorter, but when you have a bunch of parameters to check the list is *much* more compact. I love Swift more every time I learn something like this. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is a little safer, too since you don't have to worry about accidentally mistyping a != as a == for example. A typo like that could be easy to miss.

Comment: Which is precisely the problem that caused me to post here in the first place :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create extension to dictionary:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func keysExistsAndNotEmpty(keysArray: [Key]) -> Bool {
        for key in keysArray {
            if (self[key] as! String).isEmpty {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

and after check your dictionary this way:

```
    let data = ["a": "a", "b": "b"]
    let keysArray = ["a", "b"] 
    if !data.keysExistsAndNotEmpty(keysArray) {
        // throw error
    }
```